# How to build indonesia phone number regex

Tags: c#, regex

these are some of indonesia phone number

> 08xxxxxxxxx (Consist of minimal 11 char length)
>
> 08xxxxxxxxxxx (always started with 08)

i found this one is useful

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"08[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
```

but, it only support for 12 character, if i change them into the following regex

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"08[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
```

it only support for 11 character, how do i make regex for validating to begins with `08` and minimal length is 11?

Comment: In the future, regexpal.com is useful.  Lets you test your regular expressions and has a quick reference guide.

Comment: sorry, i never heard regexpal.com before :( thank you anyway ! :)

Comment: @Cignitor Did you mean 11-12 nubmers, or at least 11 maybe more?

Comment: @CoderOfHonor at least contains 11 char, which means, may contains more than 20 char or more :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^08[0-9]{9,}$
```

The `{9,}` means "at least 9," but possibly more.

I changed it to 9 to account for the two leading digits (which would add up to 11).

Comment: the regex still accept the value "08123123123123asd" . it suppose to accept only numeric with 11 character minimum

Comment: Just change to `^08[0-9]{9,}$`.  C# may also have a "match whole expression" method (Java does), but I'm not sure

Comment: okay, could you change your regex into `^08[0-9]{9,}$` please ? so the other indonesian like me could find the answer easily :)

Answer (score 4):

```
08\d{9,10}
```

Translates to "begins with 08"; Minimum 11 maximum, 12 digits long.

edit: count.

Comment: Whoa there! Why so many upvotes? This translates to _contains_ a string starting with 08. Also if the `^` had been at the beginning, the min length would have been 13.

Comment: In lue of the additional comments it probably should be either:  08\d{9,10}  or 08\d{9,}  the author is unclear if max of 12 is desired, also, author doesn't state this is at the beginning of a line, so no ^ or if it as end of line, so no $.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end?

Comment: Could be.  However the ones that are working do not contain begin/end so adding ^ and/or $ would be a different check that the example given of working ones.  So, if the current numbers are embedded in a sentence "Frank's number is 08123456789"  Then an additional ^ would not find it, but the author's example would find it.

Comment: @JohnS. Well shouldn't it at least be changed from 11 to 9? Remember that the prefix of `08` is part of the number total.

Comment: excuse me, that regex accept the char like this `0856912312313asd`

Answer (score 1):

how about this pattern?

```
^08\d{9,10}$
```

this will check for 11 to 12 characters including `08`

Comment: this is not what op wants..should be `{9,}`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ so by that this pattern is allowed? `081234567891234125` ?

Comment: @JW. he never said anything about max limit

Comment: True, someone should ask him what he means.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add more complete version, here they are (with digit grouping)

```
([\[\(])?(?:(\+62)|62|0)\1? ?-? ?8(?!0|4|6)\d(?!0)\d\1? ?-? ?\d{3,4} ?-? ?\d{3,5}(?: ?-? ?\d{3})?\b
```

It will accept format such

`(0811) 123 123`

`[62] 812 1234567`

`0812 345 6789`

`+62856123456789`

`0878-123-123-123`

`[+62823] 1234 - 56789`   ---> I believe this is the longest phone number as the time of writing

Answer (score 0):

```
((\+62 8\d{2}([ -])|08\d{2}([ -]?)|\+628\d{2})\d{4}(\3\4)\d{2,5})
```

this will accept most used style like
`08xx xxxx xxxx`
`08xxxxxxxxxxxx`
`08xx-xxxx-xxxx`
`+628xxxxxxxxxx`
`+62 8xx xxxx xxxx`
`+62 8xx-xxxx-xxxx`
also this will check for 11-13 long numbers
sorry for the grammar though