# best way to handle regex phone number in onChangeText react native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, textinput

I want to handle phone number field in `onChangeText` `TextInput` `React native`,

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617994/8943429) i can use `^08[0-9]{9,}$` pattern, but the problem is on first number, regex wont allow 0 because of `08` on regex pattern, and if i add `0|08...`, regex allow 0 but it's allow any number on 2nd number instead of 08.

**My Question :**
what is the best way to force regex handle first number is 0 and second number is 8? so i get 08xxxxxxxxxx (when x is another number 0-9)

and here is an example of my current code in `reactJS`, you can feel i can type any number after i'm typing 0, and for new suggested regex `(^0|08[0-9]{9,}$)` i can't type any number anymore after 0,

> Notes: i don't know why my question marked as duplicate since the duplicated not help me to fix my issue

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let reg = /^0|08[0-9]{9,}$/
    if(reg.test(event.target.value)){
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Phone:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to match and not match, can you give a few examples of both matches and non-matches required.

Comment: @iakobski you can try my snippet above to fell what i really want, all i want is just lock first seconds number to `08`, but if i do `08[0-9]{9,}` regex, user can't type 0 at textbox

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use *groups* in regular expressions.

The solution to your problem: `/^(0|08|08[0-9]{1,9})$/`

Explanation: Capture if it's a `0` or `08` or `08x` or `08xx` or `08xxx` or `08xxxx` ... upto `08xxxxxxxxx` ( i.e upto 9 x's, and x can be any single digit number ).

Comment: You can simplify the above mentioned regular expression and rewrite it as : ```/^(0|08[0-9]{0,9})$/```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses to show where your alternatives start and end. If you don't it will extend to the whole regex, including the start/end assertions. So in your regex `^0|08[0-9]{9,}$` the first alternative is zero at the start of the string, ignoring anything that follows, the second alternative is your 08xxxxxxxx at the end of the string, ignoring anything before that. Try `^(0|08[0-9]{9,})$` if you want to match just `0` on its own as well as 08xxxxxxxxx

Comment: `^(0|08[0-9]{9,})$` not help on 2nd number, i can't even type 8

Comment: It's not clear what you want, this is from your original question. See my comment to your post and provide examples.